# How to fix an S3457 report in SonarQube

Tags: java, sonarqube

I am using what felt like correct Java code in order to trace sections of a program:

```
LOG.debug("a simple string with no formatters nor placeholders.");
```

However, SonarLint in Eclipse is showing the following report on that line:

> String contains no format specifiers.

The matching rule, S3457, reads "Printf-style format strings should be used correctly (squid:S3457)".

I am using logback and the `LOG` variable in the code above is of type `org.slf4j.Logger`.

I'd like to clear this report, and in the meantime, learn something.

Can someone enlighten me as to what is wrong in this? Or is it a case of Sonar being too strict in applying that rule?

Otherwise, is it considered bad practice to output a log message without outputting values?

Comment: I think this link would be helpful- https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48683723/sonarqube-string-contains-no-format-specifiers-when-logging-constant-string-m

Answer (score 1):

I think this might be an issue with the latest version of SonarQube.

I've found the following [report](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/sonarqube/DyG-u8pmocQ), where the following code produced a false positive of the same issue you encountered:

```
log.trace("Connection closed");
```

The SonarQube representative has said that this is a known issue and that they should have a fix ready for it.

Comment: Thank you. My question is indeed a duplicate as mentioned by someone else and in the other question they refer to, the SonarQube people say the fix is in 6.7 LTS, but I'm running 6.7.1 and I still see this. I'll take it to them.

Comment: @AbVog : Happy to help. Love SonarQube/SonarLint.